# Do these two sentences mean the same thing or is there a grammar rule I am unaware of that distinguishes a difference?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

What's the difference in meaning between the following two sentences and is one more correct than the other?

> I was wondering if it's OK to once in a while come to Wednesday
>   morning running practices?
>
> I was wondering if it's OK to once in a while come to a Wednesday
>   morning running practice?

Comment: *Is it O.K, if I came to the occasional Wednesday morning running practice?* OR "I was wondering, if it was O.K to come on the occasional Wednesday morning practice?"

Answer (score 1):

> *I was wondering if it's ok to once in a while come to a Wednesday
>   morning running practice?* or perhaps more idiomatically to some ears *I
>   was wondering if it's ok to come to a Wednesday morning running
>   practice once in a while?* / *I was wondering if it's ok once in a while
>   to come to a Wednesday morning running practice?* [adverbials are quite
>   mobile within sentences, but often sound more natural in certain
>   positions].

is certainly fine with 'the odd occasion' meaning.

> *I was wondering if it's ok to once in a while come to Wednesday
>   morning running practices?*

is probably meant to be taken the same way, but could also mean that there are different sessions each Wednesday, or that the speaker has in mind, for instance, 'those in June and those in September'. 'Once in a while' is synonymous with 'now and then', 'from time to time' and the 'once' can refer to one period as well as one occasion. 'Every once in a while, United manage to string together three or four consecutive wins.'

Comment: Is the first "quoted" paragraph meant to be all quoted?

Comment: I'm trying to clarify within the restrictions of the possible formatting. Sorry if I'm breaking any prescriptivisms.

Answer (score -2):

*Come to Wednesday practices* means you plan to regularly join the practice.

*Come to A Wednesday practice* means you will show up once (in a while in your case, so more than once).

Hence the first example is not syntactically correct when using once in a while

> I was wondering if it's OK to once in a while come to a Wednesday morning running practice?

is the better sentence of the two.

> May I occasionally join your Wednesday running practices?

perhaps or

> May I join your Wednesday running practices once in a while?

Comment: Other than the main point about which I agree with your answer, it is a dreadfully clumsy sentence. Quite apart from the split infinitive, there is no punctuation and it is excessively wordy. 'Once in a while' is a very chatty register. I would say: 'Would it be alright if, occasionally, I joined in your Wednesday morning running practice?'

Comment: I agree with the clumsiness.